# Javascript countdown call asp.net codebehind code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When running default.aspx, I need to call the asp.net codebehind function Search(int count). First time the function is called, int count should be 5. If the function returns True, the function should not run again.

If the function returns false, run the function again with count = 4. If it still returns false, run the function again with count = 3. Do this until count = 0. It should be 1 second between each time the funtions runs.

Is there a smart way to solve this by jacascript in default.aspx?

---

### default.aspx

```
Javascript here...

<asp:Literal runat="server" id="litStatus" />
```

---

### default.aspx.cs

```
protected bool Search(int count)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        if (Something....)
        {
            litStatus.Text = "Found";
            status = true;
        }
        else
        {
            litStatus.Text = string.Format("Please wait ({0})...", count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        litStatus.Text = "Not found";
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the search function to WebMethod

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static object Search(int count)
    {
        bool status = false;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                return new { Result = true, StatusText = "Found" };
            }
            else
            {
                return new { Result = false, StatusText = string.Format("Please wait ({0})...", count) }; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new { Result = false, StatusText = "Not found" };

        } 
    }
```

change the lteral id mode :

```
 <asp:Literal runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" id="litStatus" />
```

then call the webmethod using Jquery

```
   <script>  
        let count = 5;
     var   callSearch = function () {
            var Data = JSON.stringify({ count: count });

            $.ajax({

                url: "/Default.aspx/Search",
                data: Data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
$('#litStatus'').text(response.d.StatusText );
                    if (!response.d.Result) {
                        --count;
                        if (!count==0) { 
                            setTimeout(callSearch, 1000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        callSearch()

    </script>
```

and your done ..  hope  my answer helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that I need to set litStatus.Text = "Not found" etc in code behind. Since the WebMethod is static it is not possible (cannot access non-static field in static context / cannot access non-static property in static context).

Comment: You can Acoummplish this by return the value from the webmethod and set the value to the litStatus in Javascrip , check the last edit on my answer